# google sheets - Auto fill formula in column

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to do something I think is quite simple, but any of the examples I find for google sheets doesn't seem to work.

I have a Master Account list that I've created which pulls from various sources.  In the last column (let's call it column L) it needs to lookup a value and return another (vlookup, have this working).

This master sheet has 3500 lines and it's a pain to have to drag down (since auto fill down) doesn't work all the time.  So I'm trying to use a script that will execute essentially a vlookup for column L based on what's already in Column A that ends on the last line of Column A's data.  I tried the following but the sample but get random method errors or that the .getSomthingCommand doesn't exist when it tries to autofill.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Master List"));
  ss.getRange("L2").setFormula("=vlookup($A2,'SFDC Report'!$A:$J,6,false)");
  
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getSheetValues(2, 12, lr-1)
  ss.getRange("L2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the formula you require, have you tried turning it into an Array Formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) if you post your formula i can edit it for you to test.

Cheers,